# asp ADO connection Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Tags: oop, asp-classic, ado

dear all pro programmer here, im totally new in here, and i might dont know how to correctly as a question here..

if i may ask for help, could u pls here here here...
im having problem with simple asp with oop structure...

help me with function savedata pls. when run,

```
call savedata("insert","test_","name, id","lalala, 222","User_ID=3")
```

got error :

INSERT INTO test_ (name, id) VALUES (lalala, 222)

... Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'Conn'

```
<%
function declare_conn(sql,atr)

dim conn, conn_
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn = Connect()
set conn_ = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strConnect = _T("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;"
     "Database=MyDatabase;User=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword;Option=4;");

if Cstr(atr)="open" then
    conn_.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    conn_.Open sql, conn, 3, 2
    set conn_.ActiveConnection = nothing
    set declare_conn=conn_
else if Cstr(atr)="exec" then
        conn.Open
        conn.Execute sql
    end if
end if
end function


function calldata(a,b,c,d)

dim conn_string, sql_string

    if c<>"" and d<>"" then
        sql_string="SELECT "&Cstr(a)&" FROM "&Cstr(b)&" WHERE "&Cstr(c)&" = '"&Cstr(d)&"'"
        response.write(sql_string)
    else
        sql_string="SELECT "&Cstr(a)&" FROM "&Cstr(b)
        response.write(sql_string)
    end if

set conn_string = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set conn_string = declare_conn(sql_string,"open")
set calldata = conn_string

end function


function savedata(a,b,c,d,e)

dim conn_string, sql_string, c_, d_, update_string
update_string = ""  
    if Cstr(a)="insert" then
        sql_string="INSERT INTO "&Cstr(b)&" ("&Cstr(c)&") VALUES ("&Cstr(d)&")"
    end if
    response.write(sql_string)
    'response.end
    if Cstr(a)="update" then
        c_ = split(c,", ",-1)
        d_ = split(d,", ",-1)
        response.write(c_)
        response.end
        if ubound(c_) = ubound(d_) then
            do while not c_.eof
                update_string=update_string&"("&Cstr(c_)&"="&Cstr(d_)&"),"
                c_.MoveNext : d_.MoveNext
            loop
        else
            %><script type="text/javascript">alert("save function error: array out of bound");</script> <%
        end if
        if Cstr(e)<>"" then
            sql_string="UPDATE "&Cstr(b)&" SET "&update_string&" WHERE "&Cstr(e)
        else
            sql_string="UPDATE "&Cstr(b)&" SET "&update_string
        end if
    end if

'set conn_string = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
call declare_conn(sql_string,"exec")
end function
%>
```

wht is tht error actually mean? i create a connection to database ADO in

```
connect()
```

still, i can run without problem for

```
calldata()
```

---

> editing-dwerty_weird

---

SOrry for the ruckus..

for this question, i find out, tht i missing "Set" for:

```
set conn=Connect()
```

sorry for the trouble... but for other question, i having problem with

```
call savedata("update","test_","name, id","'lalala', 222","bil=1")
```

it will get error : 
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 
Object required 
/bkpi-msn/SPPro/function.asp, line 56 –

can anyone help me?

Comment: for this question, i find out, tht i missing "Set" for:
set conn=Connect()

sorry for the trouble...

but for other question, i having problem with 

    call savedata("update","test_","name, id","'lalala', 222","bil=1")

it will get error :

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 

Object required 

/bkpi-msn/SPPro/function.asp, line 56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're missing single quotes in your data**. Value for name is a string and should be wrapped in single quotes.

You have already implemented this in calldata() that is why it is working fine. Update the same for savedata too.

> Note: This applies for all the string parameters and may apply in some
>   other way (using #) for date / datetime parameters too.

*Please use this as a starting point and follow best-practices for development!*

Hope this helps!

Vivek

Comment: ty for replying... 
somehow, the error pointing to conn.Execute syntax... 
i try change the string , and the error still pointing to same place...

Comment: @dwerty_weird, the error would always point to conn.Execute as this is where database is trying to execute the query. Could you paste the query you're creating? (The final query, just before conn.Execute)

Comment: ty for replying...
INSERT INTO test_ (name,id) VALUES ('lalala',222) tht will be the final query before execute... as, single quotes will be write in call function... as savedata("insert","test_","name,id","'lalala',222","bil=1")... i manage to solve tht problem.. but i got another problem...

Comment: is this the final query you're getting? `INSERT INTO test_ (name,id) VALUES ('lalala',222)` - this seems alright! If this is not what you're getting, could you provide what you're getting? What another problem did you get into?